# Jenkins Enable Security doesnt work

Tags: jenkins

I tried to enable Jenkins CI security according to [instructions in the wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Standard+Security+Setup) (the “Initial Steps” part). When I save the configuration, the browser asks me for some credentials, but since I haven't set any yet there is no way to get in to create a new user account (according the page above) and as a result I'm getting

```
Status Code: 401, Exception: Bad credentials
```

Answer (score 2):

To get back into Jenkins, look at this page: [Help! I Locked Myself Out](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Disable+security).

To prevent what happened from happening again, I have always found it easiest to enable the security (I'm not sure which method you set), and then add my own user with the "Add" button.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using Chrome on Linux and getting locked out every time by
an auth popup as soon as I saved the security settings. 
I found that using either a Chrome "Incognito Window" or Firefox worked Ok.